# MongoDB - Is find() realtime?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

Using the [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) npm package, in a node.js app, if I acquire a collection object early in a long-running node.js async script, like this:

```
var collection = await db.collection(collectionName);
```

If the collection gets modified before I execute the `find()` method, of this collection object, will the results of `find({})` be current, or will it only show data as it was at the time I acquired the collection object?

For example, let's hypothetically assume that 10 minutes later the script gets to a line like this:

```
let cursor = await collection.find({});
```

Additionally assume that during this lapse of time, items were added, removed and modified before `find()` was called.

Will the resulting cursor navigate current data or will the data be as it was at the time that I acquired the collection object (at the beginning of the script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt it would take a snapshot of the collection when you acquire it.

See:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/

Return value of `find` will be a cursor to the current state.

> Wil the resulting cursor navigate current data or will the data be as
>   it was at the time that I acquired the collection object (at the
>   beginning of the script)?

The resulting cursor runs through current data.

Comment: Also, what if items are added, removed and modified while I'm navigating the cursor? Does the cursor-data remain current or is it a snapshot of when I called the find() method?

Comment: IDK TBH, `toArray()` creates a snapshot of matching documents in the RAM by iterating through the cursor.  So that means a snapshot, but that also _iterates through the cursor_, so the question remains. Easiest is to write a small example where you query a collection and then run a loop which waits for a keypress every iteration, steps the cursor once and prints the result. You can try inserting/updating/deleting documents meanwhile and see if the results are affected.